# Is there a way to exclude some code from production version?

Tags: meteor

I want to add a logging system in my app for development mode only and I don't want it to be included in my minified/uglyfied production version.

I know I can check if I am in development or production mode using `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but I assume the code wrapped in this kind of check will be included production version even if it will not run. Is that true?

If so, is there a way to exclude from production versions a part of my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct - wrapping the code in an `if` will still still include it in the bundle. Instead, you can solve this by moving your code into a package and using `debugOnly: true` in the `Package.describe` section. That will allow the package to be used when in development mode but not included in the minified version for production. Here's an example:

```js
Package.describe({
  name:    "awesome",
  summary: "My awesome package",
  version: "1.0.0",
  debugOnly: true
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.addFiles('lib/something.js');
});
```

Also see the `package.js` for [mongol](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol/blob/master/package.js).

**Important note**: Exported symbols from `debugOnly` packages don't currently work. See [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3639) for more details. You can still access them, but you'll have to do something like `Package.awesome.exportedSymbol`.